# Proving a complicated summation problem

Tags: summation

I'm trying to solve a complicated summation problem where there are two multiplication problems that both have $i$. I'm entirely lost. I would be thankful for any help.

How is it possible to possible to find the sum of this expression (with a proof)?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i(2^i)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate this sum by rearranging the terms:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n i(2^i) &= 2^1 + 2\cdot2^2 + 3\cdot 2^3 + \cdots + n\cdot 2^n\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i + \sum_{i=2}^n 2^i + \sum_{i=3}^n 2^i +\cdots + 2^n\\
&= (2^{n+1} - 2^1) + (2^{n+1}-2^2) + (2^{n+1} - 2^3) + \cdots + (2^{n+1} - 2^n)\\
&= n2^{n+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = n2^{n+1} - (2^{n+1} - 2) = (n-1)2^{n+1} + 2
\end{align*}

If you participate in a lot of math competitions, this trick is a handy one to know.

Comment: that is a very handy trick I would never had gotten. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, which yields a more general result.  Start with the formula for the sum of a geometric series.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
Differentiate with respect to $x$.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i x^{i-1} = \frac{n x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(1-x)^2}$$
Multiply by $x$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i x^i =\sum_{i=0}^n i x^i = x \left( \frac{n x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(1-x)^2} \right)$$
Now take the special case $x=2$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i 2^i = 2\;[n 2^{n+1}-(n+1)2^n+1]$$